# Insert data from database on load of form

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, sql-server-2012

I'm new here need help creating a payroll management system in C# using SQL Server 2012.

I have created a login form and I want to use it on user login;

For example I have a user with the username `sami` and a password of `shaikh`. When a user clicks on login button, it automatically opens a new form and loads that particular user data into the new form.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to answer this question? Can you at least provide some sql for the login lookup? One additional point that concerns me greatly is that this question is so basic. How do you expect to write an entire payroll management system when you can't figure something this simple out on your own?

Comment: Help us to help you. Show us the code snippets where you are stuck and / or the error traces and other relevant info..

Comment: I would suggest to do a quick Google, follow one of the many tutorials out there and then when you get stuck come back with a specific question that people will be able to help you with. As it stands this is far to broad a question.

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this. Each with it's own advantage and disadvantage. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Create new form which to show this form if clicked on login button. Write your query in `formActive` event or `formLoad` event to execute correctly.

```
private void Login_button(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 f1=new Form1();
   f1.show();
}


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(){
    {
        this.Load+= new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    private void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //write your code
    }
}
```